# How do I store a value that was set using a pageInit function?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a client script that sets a field value based on a joined record. I can display the desired value in edit mode in the browser, but on save, the value disappears from the UI.

```
function pageInit(context) {
    var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
    var cusRec = currentRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custrecord3'
    });
        
    var cdrCus = record.load({
        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
        id: cusRec
    });
    var cdrAddr = cdrCus.getValue('defaultaddress');
    console.log(cdrAddr);

    currentRecord.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custrecord_cdr_bill_to',
        value: cdrAddr
    });
}
```

On save, the value set at `currentRecord.setValue({});` disappears from the UI. I would like to set this value on page load and persist it to the database on save. I attempted to add `currentRecord.save();` but this resulted in an error: "currentRecord.save(); is not a function"

Thank you in advance for any assistance you are able to provide!

Comment: Why are you loading the record. Try to get value from the currentRecord in client script and no need to save the record.

Comment: @HiddenOne1254 - it's not the record in context that's being loaded; it's a separate record.  Potentially,  `search.lookupFields` instead of `record.load` could run a little faster, but maybe the customer record is needed for something else.  @uvebrendal - check that the custom field `custrecord_cdr_bill_to` has Store Value checked in the field definition page.

Comment: I am saying him/her to read value from the context.currentRecord. There is no need to load the record in client script as it is not server side script.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageInit(context)
        {
            log.debug('Mode:', context.mode);
            var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
            
            if (context.mode == 'edit')
            {
                
                var cdrAddr = currentRecord.getValue('defaultaddress');
                console.log(cdrAddr);
        
                currentRecord.setValue({
                  fieldId: 'custrecord_cdr_bill_to',
                  value: cdrAddr
                });
            }
            
        }
```

Try this approach. As client script is UI script no need to load the record.Here I am using edit mode so this script should only trigger in edit mode.